# Unity not executing C# scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity not running scripts. No errors, no warnings, it just won't run.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TryScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("space key was pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Apparently, attaching the same script to several components of the game object will cause the script to not run. Now after removing the redundant components and restarting the game, the script works fine.

Comment: Did you actually attach it to a game object in your active scene?

Comment: Yes, I did this before, and I did it again just now but the script still doesnt work. I created two cubes, one is floating and is a rigidBody the other is underneath and is not a rigidBody. So when I start the game the first cube should fall on the second (and it works fine).  I attached the script to the falling cube by draging it into the Cube object (the rigid one)on the Hierarhhy tab. I will updated the OP with the new screens.

Comment: Make sure the script is attached and enabled (has the check mark next to the name) on the object. None of the screenshots shows it attached.

Comment: The same script was attached to the same game object more than 1 time (4 components that links to the same script were added to the game object). I am not sure of this but it might be the cause since it works now after restarting the game and removing the redundant script components. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, attaching the same script to several components of the game object will cause the script to not run. Now after removing the redundant components and restarting the game, the script works fine.